# how do I deeply compare 2 objects using Cypress

Tags: cypress, chai, assertion

I want to compare a response from an Api request against a benchmark

Json response looks like this

```
projects: [
      {
        description: "",
        id: 6823,
        title:
          "",
      },
    ]
```

My test is doing the following:

```
cy.request(
      "<api>"
    ).then((response) => {
      assert.deepEqual(
        response.body,
        greatBenches.benchTerm1
      );
    });
```

I tried the same thing using expect().to.deep.equal() and I get the same result

Expected {Object (projects)} to deeply equal {Object (projects)}

Comment: I get around this by converting both of the objects to JSON and then comparing them as strings. It’s a hack but it might work for you.

Comment: How does your benchmark look like? The JSON response you mention is not a valid JSON, so there's either a problem with your API, or you have deleted some part of the actual response.

Comment: sorry, @pavelsaman the json is the same I mention but between brackets, so it looks like
this

```
{
   projects: [
      {
        description: "",
        id: 6823,
        title:
          "",
      },
    ]
}
```